I have linear trend in my time series data. After second differencing ACF plots show it is white noise . Is differencing wrong?
I am working with time series data (predicting Harvard tuition fee). I have data of tuition fee of Harvard from 1985 to 2016. When I plot time series data, there is clear upward trend over the years. Variance and Mean are also not constant.
So then I differenced the data to make it stationary but when I plot it, it still does not look stationary. Then I did second-order differencing; unfortunately when I plot the ACF, it indicates that it is white noise because all lags are inside the bounds. I am sure this data is not white noise because there is linear trend.
I am not sure whether to difference this small data or not.
What should I do?

Increases in prices tend in a sense to be multiplicative.  Instead of simple differencing, you might want to look either at percentage changes year to year or at differences in the logarithms of prices.

Something to think about - is there a linear trend in a series after it's been differenced?  Write out a little math and see...
